# How to update values in Java(Android) array for listview (Simple shopping list app)

Tags: java, android, arrays, listview

I'm new to programming, and as practice for fun I have created a simple app that stores recipes with predetermined ingredients, which the user can put on his/her shopping list with one click per recipe. Also, individual objects can be added to the list. The app works fine to this point, but if I for example select 3 recipes that contain "Milk", milk appears on the list 3 times. Obviously it would be better to display Milk x 3 on one line. I have searched for hours for a solution with no luck.

This is how I add (and sort) the ingredients, milk and cookies for example, from a menu list:

```
if(id == R.id.action_milkAndCookies) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Milk and cookies");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Add to list", new 
         DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Collections.addAll(shoppingList, "Milk", "Cookies");
                Collections.sort(shoppingList);
                storeArrayVal(shoppingList, getApplicationContext());
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });
```

OnCreate-method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    shoppingList = getArrayVal(getApplicationContext());
    Collections.sort(shoppingList);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
shoppingList);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, final int 
position, long id) {
            String selectedItem = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
            if 
(selectedItem.trim().equals(shoppingList.get(position).trim())) {
                removeElement(selectedItem, position);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Can not be removed", 
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Output is:

Cookies
Cookies
Milk
Milk

Would like it to be:

Cookies x 2
Milk x 2

Answer (score 0):

When you want to add a new ingredient, you must have to check first if it is not already present. If present then update the number of ingredient. If not, add ingredient with value of 1. What about using a `HashMap<String, Int>` where first String is the name of your ingredient and Int is the corresponding number ?